# How to define requirement describing csv file structure in Enterprise Architect

Tags: enterprise-architect

I am learning to use Sparx Enterprise Architect for requirements management. I am wondering, what is the best practice, or any practice to describe CSV file structure (i.e. header names and their types) that will be imported by designed system?

Do you use taggeed values, or simply just "Notes" area? Or maybe just link sample csv file, but then, how to include it in printed documentation?

Thank you for advice!

Answer (score 0):

UML is, of course, not good at describing structures such as CSV formats. You can create classes with attributes "col_1", "col_2", etc, but the simplest way is probably to add a linked document to the requirement (right-click and select Create Linked Document).

The linked document can be included in a generated document quite easily. In the template editor, simply select the Linked Document node under the Element node.

These linked documents are stored inside the EA project. They are RTF, so they are very limited compared to other formats, but they support tables and other basic formatting, which is usually enough for requirement details.

Comment: Thanks @Uffe, but linked documents do not seem to be a good solution here. What if I wanted to relate to those column names later on, i.e. in class model... I don't know, maybe I am going into to much details in my model?

Comment: EA allows you to link connectors to attributes (right-click, Link to Element feature), which might be useful. Otherwise an Entity-Relationship model might be a better fit.